# Remove reference tags in compiled output

Tags: typescript

I'm compiling all `.ts` files into one file using the command

```
tsc -out app.js app.ts --removeComments
```

based on the [npm usage instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler). The problem is it still keeps all reference tags in the compiled code afterwards! As far as I'm aware, there's no use for these in JavaScript.

For example, these TypeScript files

```
Application.ts

/// <reference path="../references/backbone.d.ts" />

module Example {
  export class Application extends Backbone.View<Backbone.Model> {
    ...
  }
}
```

and

```
app.ts

/// <reference path="Example/Application.ts" />

import Application = Example.Application;

class App extends Application {
  ...
}
```

will compile into something like

```
/// <reference path="../references/backbone.d.ts" />
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    ...
};
var Example;
(function (Example) {
    var Application = (function (_super) {
       ...
    })(Backbone.View);
    Example.Application = Application;
})(Example || (Example = {}));
/// <reference path="Example/Application.ts" />
var Application = Example.Application;
var App = (function (_super) {
    ...
})(Application);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

The `sourceMappingURL` I absolutely want included, and the `--removeComments` works as expected there. But the reference tags seem pointless when sitting on the server. Is there an option to remove these from the compiled source? Or am I incorrect in thinking these are not used (possibly when debugging with source maps)?

Comment: If you are minifying your Javascript (which you should be) then those reference tags will get stripped out when your code goes to production.

Comment: I suggest creating a tsconfig.json file where you can specify all of what you wrote in command line. Plz let me know if this solves it.

Comment: It seems that TS compiler interprets all comments at the top of a file as important (copyrights or something). Actually `reference` comments are not required, you can enumerate all your files in proper order in command line or in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help everyone. Both minifying and using a tsconfig.json file are able to solve the problem in their own ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two methods to removing the references, as pointed out in the comments.

1. Using `tsconfig.json` removes the need for `/// <reference>` tags
   altogether. For example:

   ```
   /// <reference path="../references/backbone.d.ts" />
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
     },
     "files": [
       'references/backbone.d.ts'
     ]
   }
   ```

   within `tsconfig.json`.
2. If you wish to not use a config file, minifying the compiled
   JavaScript with a tool like [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) will remove all
   comments and references.

Comment: And how can you use tsconfig.json to remove all the reference tags? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Kokodoko You don't use `tsconfig.json` to remove the tags; it removes the *need* for the tags because you specify every file you wish to compile. Once every file is listed within the `files` array, you can delete the `/// <reference>` lines. I've updated my answer to add this.

Comment: Apparently I need to restart VS Code before these kind of changes take effect. It seems to be working now :) Can I also include .d.ts files this way, even if they reside in a sub folder?

Comment: You can! The path specified for each file is relative to `tsconfig.json`'s location.

Comment: Nice, however when you use the references in the tsconfig.json file, code completion in vscode no longer works for the previously referenced files.

Comment: @iMoses Good to note. I use JetBrains' IDEs and code completion works fine using `tsconfig.json`.